# Using querySelectorAll to get ALL elements with that class name, not only the first

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I've ditched jquery about 9(ish) months ago and needed a selector engine (without all the hassle and don't mind ie<7 support) so i made a simplified version of document.querySelectorAll by creating this function:

```
// "qsa" stands for: "querySelectorAll"
window.qsa = function (el) {
  var result = document.querySelectorAll(el)[0];
  return result;
};
```

This works perfectly fine for 95% of the time but I've had this problem for a while now and i have researched mdn, w3c, SO and not to forget Google :) but have not yet found the answer as to why I only get the first element with the requested class.
And I know that only the first element being returned is caused by the "[0]" at the end, but the function won't work if I remove it so I've tried to make a for loop with an index variable that increases in value depending on the length of elements with that class like this:

```
window.qsa = function (el) {
  var result, el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  for(var i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) {
   result = el[i];
  }
  return result;
};
```

Again that did not work so I tried a while loop like this:

```
window.qsa = function (el) {
  var result, i = 0, el = document.querySelectorAll(el);
  while(i < el.length) {
    i++;
  }
  result = el[i];
  return result;
};
```

By now I'm starting to wonder if anything works? and I'm getting very frustrated with document.querySelectorAll...
But my stubborn inner-self keeps going and I keep on failing (tiering cycle) so I know that now is REALLY the time to ask these questions :

**Why is it only returning the first element with that class and not all of them?**

**Why does my for loop fail?**

**Why does my while loop fail?**

And thank you because any / all help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is it being used?

Comment: Why not only using `return document.querySelectorAll(el)`?

Comment: The problem is definitely with where you're using it. Removing the [0] will return the NodeList of elements rather than a single element, so you just need to treat it as an array when accessing the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a single element. You can return the array. If you want to be able to act on all elements at once, jQuery style,  you can pass a callback into your function;

```js
window.qsa = function(query, callback) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(query);
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i) {
            callback.call(els[i], els[i], i);
        }
    }
    return els;
};


qsa('button.change-all', function(btn) {
    // You can reference the element using the first parameter
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        qsa('p', function(p, index){
            // Or you can reference the element using `this`
            this.innerHTML = 'Changed ' + index;
        });
    });
});

qsa('button.change-second', function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var second = qsa('p')[1];
        second.innerHTML = 'Changed just the second one';
    });
});
```

```html
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
<p>Three</p>

<button class='change-all'>Change Paragraphs</button>
<button class='change-second'>Change Second Paragraph</button>
```

Then you can call either use the callback

```
qsa('P', function(){
    this.innerHTML = 'test';
});
```

Or you can use the array that is returned

```
var pList = qsa('p');
var p1 = pList[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great awnser works great and saved me alot of file size and the code style is great, if i could i would upvote a million times :-)

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it only returning the first element with that class and not all of them?

Because you explicitly get the first element off the results and return that.

> Why does my for loop fail?

Because you overwrite `result` with a new value each time you go around the end of loop. Then you return the last thing you get.

> Why does my while loop fail?

The same reason.

---

If you want all the elements, then you just get the result of running the function:

```
return document.querySelectorAll(el)
```

That will give you a NodeList object containing all the elements.

---

Now that does what you say you want, I'm going to speculate about what your real problem is (i.e. why you think it doesn't work).

You haven't shown us what you do with the result of running that function, but my guess is that you are trying to treat it like an element.

It isn't an element. It is a NodeList, which is like an array.

If you wanted to, for instance, change the background colour of an element you could do this:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

If you want to change the background colour of every element in a NodeList, then you have to change the background colour of **each one** in turn: with a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < node_list.length; i++) {
    var element = node_list[i];
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Or `window.qsa = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);` but I am guessing the OP would like to do `qsa('p .something').classList.add('my-class') `

Comment: Thank you for the great in depth awnser i understand it alot more now.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; ++i) {
 result = el[i];
}
```

overwrites your result variable every time. That's why you always get only one element.

You can use the result outside though, and iterate through it. Kinda like

```
var result = window.qsa(el)
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
  var workOn = result[i];
  // Do something with workOn
}
```

Comment: I would have a million times but i don't have 15 rep points yet so sadly i can't upvote yet.

Comment: Keep it up aswell :-)